Karaf feature.xml - problem with remote repositories while downtime
I've got a problem with feature.xml or it's general karaf problem. My feature.xml and settings.xml are configured properly, but with the downtime of remote repo I'm getting 503 errors and after this downtime feature.xml do not try to refresh itself/try to fetch those packages one more time or try to do this in some interval time. Did anyone faced this issue, I've got my karaf instance running in k8s and trying to omit those problem without restarting whole pod.
Thanks in advance for any proposal/solutions.
Have a nice day and take care

You could try avoid the problem by making a custom Apache Karaf distribution with all required bundles and features pre-installed and containerizing that one instead. You could also make it static distribution which could be more fitting for k8s.

Agreed, the best way is to create your own custom distribution.
You can take a look here to have an example of custom distribution:
https://github.com/yupiik/esb
